# TypeMock trying to mock a random method?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, tools, mock

I've hit an issue that has stumped me.
I have Specflow tests that run perfectly fine on my local machine, but fail when run in the build.

The error message I get is:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String> TypeMock.Interceptors.FileInterceptor.ReadLines(System.String, System.Text.Encoding)'.
```

The code where this originates from:

```
public class FileReader : IFileReader
{
    public List<string> ReadLines(string fileFullPath)
    {
        return File.ReadLines(fileFullPath, Encoding.ASCII).ToList();
    }
}
```

To me, it appears as if TypeMock is trying to mock the `File.ReadLines()` method. However, there isn't a single line of code in the solution that requests this method to be mocked.

Does anybody have an idea what might be going on here?
Why do I get that strange exception? And what is the cause of the difference between the outcome when the tests are run locally or in a build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in TypeMock. It has been fixed in version 8.6.0.18.